# Memory management issue with NSString

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsstring

I have NSMutableArray* cityData that I fill with custom LocationDetail objects. cityData is created in viewDidLoad and released in dealloc.
Somewhere in the code, based on user actions, I populate LocationDetail and add it to cityData array:

```
LocationDetail* d = [[LocationDetail alloc] init];
    d.city = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", (char*)sqlite3_column_text16(statement, 1)];
    d.tz = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", (char*)sqlite3_column_text16(statement, 3)];
    d.country = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", (char*)sqlite3_column_text16(statement, 2)];
    d._id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", (char*)sqlite3_column_text16(statement, 0)];

    [cityData addObject:d];
    [d release];
```

When I am finished with the view controller and remove it, Leaks utility says I have a leak in the code above in NSCFString in all 4 lines with [NSString stringWithFormat] above.

I tried removing the sqlite3 stuff and simplified the call to something like

```
d._id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", "a string"]
```

with the same result. However, if I replace the NSString stringWithFormat like this:

```
d._id = @"a string";
```

the leak goes away. I wonder why there is a leak if I use the stringWithFormat, but not if I use @"something". Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Show how you defined each `@property` (`city`, `tz`, `country` and `_id`) for `LocationDetail`

Comment: The properties of LocationDetail are all NSStrings* and defined his way: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* _id;

Comment: @interface LocationDetail : NSObject {
    
    NSString* city;
    NSString* tz;
    
    NSString* country;
 NSString* _id;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* tz;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* country;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* _id;

@end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are not automatically released for you, you need to do that yourself in

```
- (void)dealloc
```

See [The Objective-C Programming Language: Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) for an example.

---

Edit:

It seems that the example was moved into the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1).

Comment: Unfortunately that link is now broken.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I've updated the post with a more current link.